# Routing to External Link with Reach Router

Tags: reach-router

I'm trying to do exactly this but with Reach Router instead of React Router:

[React-Router External link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link)

Comment: Do the things with the simplest way as possible, Link component is just a `<a>` tag (html link) with more stuffs.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by [@Sagiv b.g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3148807/sagiv-b-g) on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46176608/7252233):

> react-router meant to "route" in a Single Page Applications. when you want to route to an external page that's not routing on a single page.

You should use `window.location`, or plain old HTML `<a href="url" ...`