# React - How to redirect to url website with attirbut to

Tags: reactjs

I wouldlike to redirect in another page when I click on one button of my menu :

```
<HeaderLink to="http://google.com" activeClassName="active-page">
          <NavText
              variant="h6"
              noWrap
              component="div"
          >
            Redirect
          </NavText>
        </HeaderLink>
        

const HeaderLink = styled(NavLink)(({ theme }) => ({
  display: 'flex',
  position: 'relative',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
...
```

but get an error. I can't redirect to google.

Comment: Could you look at this Q/A : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176506/using-navlink-with-external-url

Comment: Is there any reason to use a NavLink for this? This isn't directing to a route, it's navigating the window to a new location. Why not use a regular `<a>` element, with whatever styles you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
<HeaderLink
  to={{ pathname: "https://google.com" }}
  activeClassName="active-page"
>
  <NavText variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
    Redirect
  </NavText>
</HeaderLink>;
```

Comment: I don't to use <a> balise but when I try your code it redirect me to this : http://0.0.0.0:8181/https://google.com instead of just this : https://google.com